# Deallocate memory after kill in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program in C which is using a few processes, semaphores and mapped memory. When I map the memory and then the program fails in the middle of progress so it cant get to the stage when memory is released, the program is stucked and I have to kill it (Ctrl+C).

The problem is that when I fix the bug and run the program again - it calls the shared memory error or semaphores error and program is terminated. I can fix this problem only by restarting the whole OS.

Is there another way, how to "deallocate" allocated memory after unexpected error?

FYI: ipcs doesn't show this allocated memory nor the semaphores used.

EDIT: I had to tag just one "right" answer, but I would like to thank you all for the ideas. The result is that after the problem occurs, deleting everything except pulse... in /dev/shm folder is the solution.

Comment: I don't believe `ipcs` would show POSIX shm segments (i.e. `shm_open()`) but only SysV IPCs (e.g. `shmget`).

Comment: So you say - since I am using POSIX way, I will always have to reboot the OS?

Comment: You could add a SIGINT/SIGTERM handler to unmap the memory.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot, but you might end up needing to perform some tricky acrobatics, such as installing a signal handler for `SIGABRT`, `SIGSEGV`, etc and properly deallocating the resources. Nte

Comment: However, I'd personally avoid any kind of POSIX/SysV IPCs for this reason -- they can potentially pollute your system and would not be removable until a reboot (or until some maintenance utility solves it). On linux you might be able to find stuff in `/dev/shm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX shared memory doesn't have a specific command-line tool. But it is typically mapped into the /dev/shm tree where you can manage the segments with classic file manipulation tools.

Answer (score 2):

Grapsus's comment is correct for POSIX shared memory.  Forget the ipcrm, it's SysV only.  Dig around in /dev/shm and remove the file that "represents" your shared memory slab.

You probably should also put in a signal handler to remove the shared memory upon a kill.  It won't work if you are going to kill with SIG_KILL (9), but it will work with most of the lesser kills.  Once the signal handler is in place, regular kills will call the handler which can then programmatically remove the shared memory before process shutdown.